# Copy char to a array with a function - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, copy

Function.h

```
void copyArray(char, char);
```

Main.cpp

```
void copyArray(char word[], char temp[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) temp[i] = word[i];
}
```

auther.cpp

```
copyArray("CHAMPAGNE", char myArray[50]);
```

Output

```
C2664   'void copyArray(char,char)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [10]' to 'char'
```

already googled the error, look for function precoded, found nothing
I must not use string

Comment: Do you want `void copyArray(char c, char array[]);` ?

Comment: The declaration of `copyArray` doesn't match the definition. Also, you can't just invent syntax like `copyArray("CHAMPAGNE", char myArray[50];);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo ````copyArray("CHAMPAGNE", char myArray[50]);```` i dont understand what is wromg ? ( the semicolon after myArray is a mistake, this is not in my code)

Comment: Note that `temp[i] = word[i]` will be Undefined Behaviour when `i` is greater or equal to the length of `word`. Also, I'd refer to your c++ book on how to call a function....

Comment: @Jeffrey yep, but i cant make it work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: The declaration and definition don't match since the declaration specifies that the function takes two `char`s while the definition specifies that the function takes two `char*`:

```
void copyArray(char, char); // declaration

void copyArray(char word[], char temp[]) { // definition
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) temp[i] = word[i];
}
```

You need to make the declaration the same as the definition:

```
void copyArray(char[], char[]); // or void copyArray(char*, char*);
```

... but, in order to copy from string literals, you need to make the first argument take a `const char*` since string literals consists of `const char`s.

```
void copyArray(const char word[], char temp[]);
```

There are however not `50` `char`s in `"CHAMPAGNE"` so trying to copy that many will make your function access `"CHAMPAGNE"` out of bounds (with undefined behavior as a result). You shouldn't copy beyond the `\0` terminator:

```
void copyArray(const char* word, char* temp) {
    do {
        *temp++ = *word;
    } while(*word++ != '\0'); // stop when \0 has been copied
}
```

But make sure that `temp` has enough room for the larget string you try to copy into it.

If you want to copy `CHAMPAGNE` into `myArray`, you need to declare `myArray` first and supply it as an argument to the function:

```
char myArray[50];
copyArray("CHAMPAGNE", myArray);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3fxa4jhcc)

Comment: And then, after fixing this, you can throw away `copyArray()` and just use `strncpy()` (or equivalent) instead, which does the same thing as `copyArray()` only safer, eg: `char myArray[50]; strncpy(myArray, "CHAMPAGNE", sizeof(myArray));`